# "The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas url"?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm building an application for WP7 using the Facebook C# SDK. When I attempt to post a message to a users wall (Just a plain message) everything works fine. But when I attempt to post a link to the users wall I get this exception message:

> (OAuthException) (#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have heard of canvas applications but I didn't think this applied to a phone app. Perhaps this is a setting on Facebook?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Here is the code I used to post to facebook:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _fbClient.PostCompleted +=
            (o, er) =>
                {
                    if (er.Error == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(er.Error.Message);
                    }
                };

        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args["name"] = "Hello World!!"; 
        args["link"] = "http://www.nfl.com"; 
        args["caption"] = ""; 
        args["description"] = ""; 
        args["picture"] = ""; 
        args["message"] = "Hello World from application."; 
        args["actions"] = "";

        FacebookAsyncCallback callback = new FacebookAsyncCallback(this.postResult);
        _fbClient.PostAsync("me/feed", args, callback);
    }

    private void postResult(FacebookAsyncResult asynchResult)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
```

NOTE: If I remove the string from "link" it works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem ["here"](http://groups.google.com/group/facebooker/browse_thread/thread/7ef5f8a4b33e72c5). In your app settings within Facebook you have to set "Stream Post Url Security" to false. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Any other solutions. Mine is set to Disabled and I am still having the problem. I have noticed that if I use the app under the context of my user account it works fine. If I use it under the context of a company page it doesn't work.

Comment: I face the same problem with @meanbunny , even when I had set "Stream Post URL Security" to false.

Comment: Glad I found your answer quickly.  I would never have guessed that that was the security setting needing toggling based upon its name.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Facebook App. Edit its settings. On the Advanced settings page, disable the "Stream post URL security" option.