# Include a picture in a wall post using the Graph api explorer tool

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

Is there any way to post a picture? I found references on how to post it from own apps, but what about using the Graph api explorer tool? Btw, I'm not trying to upload a picture, I want to show a picture that's being stored on my server, directly in the post.

Edit1:

```
      $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$_POST['group_id']."/feed";

  $postData = array(
    'access_token' => $_POST['token'], 
    'message' => $_POST['message'],
    'picture' => 'http://admin.oceaniatravel.ro/Files/Pictures/Images/iberostar-paraiso-maya-5-419.jpg');

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $graph_url,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
  ));
  $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close($ch);
```

Edit2

The problem was that I was using the graph explorer. A really easy solution is to create an own app and when you generate the token in the explorer app you just choose your own app. Thank you!

Comment: You can add `picture` parameter with URL to picture as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) to display image in the Post.

Comment: Already tried something similar, like the code you see above. No luck. Does not picture, any clues?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also, as a suggestion, using PHP SDK will reduce difficulty in doing interaction with Facebook API.

Comment: "(#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL." I'm using the graph api explorer to post this. I'm asking whether I can post a picture from the web, I don't want to be restricted to app.

Comment: Also, something else that could help me would be a "link summary" of some link that add in there. If you go to your facebook and try to post something, you'll see that if you enter a link it will automatically create a "summary", that would be ok as well. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: I think you are trying to post the status with access token from graph explorer, which for their own security they don't allow ([check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395428/the-posts-links-must-direct-to-the-applications-connect-or-canvas-url)), so please create your own application and do the same with it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I already figured that out. You may post the answer so I can pick it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your error

```
(#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.
```

Was the fact, that you were using the access token generated through Graph Explorer. Which has its settings for `Stream Post Url Security` as `enabled` so that User may not use the Graph explorer for malicious purposes.

So, to solve the issue, create a new app, which as its default setting gets `Stream Post Url Security` as `disabled`, and then through Graph Explorer use the access token corresponding to your own app instead of Graph Explorer.